# How to fix this strange doctrine error when doing a schema update

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

My dev environment on windows 8 has been running great but all of a sudden whenever i run:

```
php  bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
```

I get a very odd error message:
[image: console]

All other developers are working completely fine in our master branch.  I've deleted the project from my local system and repulled it from git and ran through the composer install process but no luck.  That leads me to believe the problem is on my pc and not the project code.

Any ideas?

Comment: nothing in the php log or dev.log either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the copy paste of the command contained a special character.  So frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are not using a backwards slash like in your screenshot:

```
php bin\console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
```

This produces (for me) the error:

```
Could not open input file:...
```

But if instead you use this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
```

it works correct, also in case that doesn't work, try doubling up the forward slash like so:

```
php bin//console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
```